# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript and I would like to use it with React. I have a functional component that needs to be exported like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import HOC from './HOC';

interface PropsType {
  someProp: boolean;
}

const MyFunctionalComponent: React.FC<PropsType> = ({ someProp }) => {
  return(
    ...
  )
};

export default HOC(MyFunctionalComponent);
```

and `HOC.tsx` is something like this:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import Loader from './Loader';

export default function HOC(HocComponent: React.FC) {
  return function () {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <HocComponent />
      </Suspense>
    );
  };
}
```

The problem is that I get the following error and I have googled but haven't found a definite solution:

```
Type '{ someProp: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'someProp' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.  TS2322
```

Obviously, if I don't wrap `MyFunctionalComponent` with `HOC` then it works fine. What is the correct approach to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was driving me nuts! I ended up with `<Props extends object,>(Component: React.FunctionComponent<Props>) =>` as in the answer by Karlus. I suppose the type of something extending 'object' will include the union of 'Props' and 'IntrinsicAttributes', which is why this works. Thanks for asking the right question. Thanks Karlus for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you must cast the properties to the an abstract parameter like `object`.

This should work:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import Loader from './Loader';

const withLoading<P extends object> (Component: React.ComponentType<P>) => 
    class WithLoading extends React.Component<P> {
        render() {
            return (
                <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
                    <HocComponent {...this.props as P} />
                </Suspense>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default HOC;
```

And then you can simply:

```
import React from 'react';
import withLoading from './HOC';

interface PropsType {
    someProp: boolean;
}

const MyFunctionalComponent: React.FC<PropsType> = ({ someProp }) => {
    return(
        ...
    );
};

export default withLoading(MyFunctionalComponent);
```

Here's the source: https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb

Comment: Is there any more specific generalization over P that would yield P & IntrinsicAttributes? I kinda feel like extends object is scoped too wide. I tried `<Props extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes,>(Component: React.FunctionComponent<Props>) =>` to no avail. It could be that I don't understand the problem, which is why I am arriving at false conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go a step further from R.Karlus, and use `props as P & {}`

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import Loader from './Loader';

const withLoading<P extends object> (Component: React.ComponentType<P>) => 
    class WithLoading extends React.Component<P> {
        render() {
            return (
                <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
                    <HocComponent {...this.props as P & {}} />
                </Suspense>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default HOC;
```